# Does Itext5 (XmlWorker) accept flexbox?

Tags: itext

In my project, I want to convert html to pdf with xmlworker.
But xmlworker does not render flexbox. The content is not styling in pdf.

Comment: What is flexbox?

Comment: it is css3 layout model

Comment: You could try with iText 7 and the pdfHtml add-on, it is a complete rewrite of XMLWorker and has much better CSS support.

Comment: No, XmlWorker does not support any of the flexbox properties and never will. pdfHtml, the equivalent of XmlWorker for itext7, when it is released, will not support any of the flexbox properties right away, but does have better CSS support for many other properties, and it might get flexbox support later down the line.

Comment: What about CSS Grid Layout Module support in iText?